# How to cancel a queue triggered Azure WebJob programatically

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, cancellation-token

I have deployed a Continuous Azure WebJob containing a procedure that gets triggered from Queue messages.

```
public Task Automation([QueueTrigger("automqueue")] string message, TextWriter log, CancellationToken token)
{
     ....
}
```

The procedure contains a `CancellationToken` that is used from the system for [graceful shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#cancellation-tokens).

Is there any programmatical way to trigger this `CancellationToken` when the user wants to cancel the process?

My automation needs allot of resources to finish and sometimes it might take several hours to be completed. This is why the user might want to cancel the process and start another.

Can I use the `CancellationToken` that i already have or I need to implement a custom solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CancelationToken` is only for shutdown notification, it is shared among all Process instances and cannot be used for other reasons.

And it is only for read, you could not change it manually , so maybe you could create a new `CancellationTokenSource` and combine the tokens into one token that will be cancelled if any of the tokens is cancelled.

Here is my code.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
            [QueueTrigger("queue2")] string message,
            ILogger logger, CancellationToken token
            )
        {

            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            string flag;
            CancellationTokenSource compositeTokenSource =
                  CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
                  tokenSource.Token, token);

            if (message.Equals("shutdown"))
            {
                logger.LogInformation(message);
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                flag = compositeTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested.ToString();
                logger.LogInformation(flag);
            }
            else {
                logger.LogInformation(message);
                flag = compositeTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested.ToString();
                logger.LogInformation(flag);
            }
        }
```

If the message equals "shutdown", the method `Cancel()` will be executed. Then the property `IsCancellationRequested` of composite token will be `true`.

Hope this will help you, if you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: I want to send a `CancellationToken` to a running process, this example uses the queue with a new message.

Comment: @Menelaos Vergis I know what you mean , you want to change CancellationToken to true , but the Token can only be read. So i try to implement it with a compositeTokenSource. And you must want to run normally if you don't want it shutdown. That's why i use message,you also could implement it with other ways.

Comment: Thank you for your insights, I understand now that this `CancelationToken` is only for shutdown notification, is shared among all Process instances and cannot be used for other reasons. Please add this information at your answer so I can mark it as solution